# rewrite a function using only pointer increment/decrement

Tags: c++

can anyone help me rewrite the function i wrote below using only points and pointer increment/decrement? I dont have much experience with pointer so I dont know what to do.

```
void reverse(char * s)
{
    int i, l = strlen(s);
    char c;
    for(i = 0; i < (l >> 1); i++)
    {
       c = s[i];
       s[i] = s[l - i - 1];
       s[l - i - 1] = c;
    }
}
```

do not use pointer arithmetic or array notation.
any help or hint on how to rewrite the function above is appriciated.
This is not a homework problem, this is one of the advance pointer program from Big C++ book. 
Thanks!

Comment: How is it possible to use pointer increment/decrement without using pointer arithmetic?

Comment: Umm, pointer increment and decrement are forms of pointer arithmetic.  Please be clear about what, specifically, you do and don't want.  Also, is this a homework problem?  If not, why only pointer increment and decrement?

Comment: What did you try? How did it not work as you expected?

Comment: "...points..." ??? Anyhow, this seems like a typical homework question, and a pretty simple one at that. If you do not have experience with pointers, why don't you read up about it, and then ask community questions on why something isn't working.

Comment: It's a one-liner I think but not without pointer arithmetic (other than increment/decrement).

Answer (score 4):

```
void reverse(char* s)
{
    char* end(s);
    while (*end) ++end;
    std::reverse(s, end);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using only pointer increments and decrements would be something like this, it can be made more compact but it becomes less readable, as it is some people might have troubles glancing over this and understanding it. The `while` can be a `for` like you have, but this is more pointer'y

Tested in GCC 4.5.1:

```
void rev(char* s)
{
    char c;
    char* e = s;
    while(*e) e++;
    e--;
    while(s < e)
    {
        c = *s;
        *s = *e;
        *e = c;
        e--;
        s++;
    }
}
```

However, if your using C++, you should be using `std::string`...

Comment: when u set char * e = s? does the pointer point to the first element of the array s or a whole array?

Comment: @RichardNguyen: The pointer points to the both first element of the array. The first element of the array is at the start of the array, so  the pointer is *also* pointing to the start of the whole array.